# PassportJS + Auth0 + KeystoneJS

Tags: node.js, passport.js, auth0, keystonejs

Is there a way to user PassportJS + Auth0 as a front end login on top of the default KeystoneJS login?

Basically, I want to keep the KeystoneJS login functionality for the back end, but use PassportJS + Auth0 for visitors. Maybe there is a way to use PassportJS + Auth0 for both, that will work as well.

Thanks!

Comment: first try something, then ask questions regarding to them.

Answer (score 2):

found a related article on this. check it out. 
[integrating-passportjs](https://blog.tableflip.io/integrating-passportjs-with-keystonejs/)

furthermore Keystone Social Login module is available but it does not support keystone versions above 3.X.x Yet!.
[keystone-social-login](https://github.com/JohnnyEstilles/keystone-social-login)